# How to define two dimensional plane?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I know that we use three non-linear (at least one of them not linear) dots to define a 3d plane, but how do we define a 2 dimensional plane ? 
I am very bad at math and yes I have searched that in the google but can't find anything, maybe that is a dumb question and we don't define planes in 2D, I don't really know.

Thanks for answers, I really need them.

Comment: I think a plane is determined by two intersecting lines

Comment: If we write like that plane is defined like that : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry), but I am trying to learn how do we define it in the math language, thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case, a plane will be determined by the span of two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: If by "3d plane", you are referring to a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then "2d plane" isn't very meaningful because a "plane" in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @suchan So you mean that everything in R^2 is simply a plane ?

Comment: @UmutPiynar I mean $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself is the plane.

Comment: @suchan Ohh, thank you for that knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We often talk about “a plane in 3D”. This is probably what you meant when you said “a 3D plane”. A plane is a 2D object, so when we are thinking in 3D we need to define *which plane* we mean by referring to some points (or lines as mentioned in the comments). In 2D the whole thing is a plane unless it’s curved like the surface of the earth or something. So there’s really nothing to define.

The crucial word is “in” - think of the plane occupying part of the 3D space. So it’s not a 3D plane, but a plane in (or embedded in) 3D.

Comment: excellent way of describing.